# Button color from drawable doesn't change

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have some issue with styling of my buttons. I use drawable  to change shape and style my app buttons. When I add background in activity xml my buttons change shape but doesn't change background color but when I add background programmatically with "setBackgroundResource" method everything is ok.
There is my piece of code:

activity xml:

```
`<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_traditional"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default_main_app"
        android:textColor="@color/mustard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:onClick="newGame"
        android:text="@string/standard_game"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_extended"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_gameChose" />
`
```

res/drawable:

```
<solid
    android:color="@color/black"
    />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="100dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    />
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:
Whole drawable code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/black"
        />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        />

</shape>
```

Comment: Post the whole drawable code. If that's it, then the drawable is wrong

Comment: Ok I had edit in main post.

Comment: Your theme also affects this behaviour.

Comment: Ok so you suggest that my theme can make some some changes also and drawable file does not override the theme setup. And i should change the theme ?

Comment: I had change "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" to "Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar" and everything work properly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the button tint is the primary color. You need to set it to null for the drawable to take effect by setting.

`app:backgroundTint="@null"`

So your whole button would look like this:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_traditional"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default_main_app"
        android:onClick="newGame"
        android:text="Standard game"
        android:textColor="#a00"
        app:backgroundTint="@null" />
```

The result:

[image: Button bg]

Comment: Your answer also made my button change Color and everything it's fine. Thanks :) Now I think which option is better to my app .

Comment: This one is better, changing your whole app theme it's not useful

Comment: I think you have right. Thank you guys for your fast, concrete answers, and your time .